# getting input from last input-areas in an array of dynamically generated text inputs

Tags: jquery, html, textinput

In this piece of code, whenever you click the OK button, a number is displayed below it and right next to that number is an input field. This happens 10 times, each time a new number is displayed along with an input field. What I'm trying to do is this: whenever the OK button is hit, things are displayed and the last user input is stored in var temp and to check it, I append it to "begin".

```
    var NumberOfQuestions= 10;
    var questionCounter = 1;
    var score=0;

    //create the Problem array
    var QuestionArray = [];
    QuestionArray.push(0);
    for (i=1; i<=NumberOfQuestions; i++){
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*110);
        QuestionArray.push(randomNumber);
        }//end for loop



    $(function() {
    $("#ok").click(function() {
        if(questionCounter <= NumberOfQuestions){
            $("#ok").after("<p>" + QuestionArray[questionCounter]  + "<input type='text' size='1' class='r'/></p>");
            questionCounter++;}//end if
          var temp = (".r").value();
          $("#hg").append(temp);        
        });//end click function
    });


});
```

begin

OK

The problem is that nothing gets stored in the variable temp. I tried var temp = (".r").val(); but that doesn't help too. pls help

Comment: $(".r").val(); //missing $ maybe also try setting $(".r").val("like this see if it stores anything");

Comment: Oops.....forgot it here.Doesn't work with the $ too.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the value after adding the new input `temp` is empty becouse the input is still empty.
Take the last input you generate before you add the new input like this:

```
$(function() {
$("#ok").click(function() {
    var temp = $(".r").last().val();
    $("#hg").append(temp); 
    if(questionCounter <= NumberOfQuestions){
        $("#ok").after("<p>" + QuestionArray[questionCounter]  + "<input type='text'          size='1' class='r'/></p>");
        questionCounter++;}//end if               
    });//end click function
});
```

Comment: yes. the problem with the code you suggest is that now nothing happens when i click the ok button !

Comment: You use val() or value()? val() is the right.(I have a mistake)